# iPad Ibooks Javascript Canvas DrawImage does not work

Tags: ipad, canvas, epub, drawimage, ibooks

I have a below script, its working in my windows browser. but this code does not work in Epub ebook (in my iPad iBooks)

```
<canvas id="e" width="177" height="113"></canvas>
<script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById("e");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var myImg = new Image();
    myImg.src = "../Images/box.jpg";
    myImg.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(myImg, 0, 0); 
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that’s correct. It seems iBooks supports a lot of canvas, but not the drawImage function. I submitted this to Apple a month or two ago and have yet to receive a response as to whether this is a bug or expected behavior. It’s possible there’s some security reason this doesn’t work, but that would seem odd considering it does in mobile Safari.

Answer (score 0):

*First, a question to Derrick Schultz. How did you submit a bug report to Apple?*

Well, here's my own findings.

**Platform**: iPad iBooks. EPUB. Javascript.

## Canvas. drawImage() function.

Does not work. Not even when the page is "refreshed" (or re-paginated? By rotating the iPad). This solution is a complete no-go.

A previous solution now seems to be the only partial workaround.

So, yes. Canvas and drawImage() does not work in iPad.

## Hidden  elements, rendered onscreen first

I created  elements for all the images I wanted to *display via interactivity (Javascript)*.

**Critical step**. I ensured that all images are rendered (visible) onscreen first. I had to do a setTimeout() for this.

*Question: What is the iBooks event that lets me know all images are rendered onscreen? `windows.onLoad` doesn't work. Even `onLoad` for all the individual images doesn't work.*

I then hid (`display: none`) all images, and displayed them upon user input.

Works.

The only problem is that big pictures that don't all fit onscreen (because I have to display them *all* first) won't work. They are not rendered onscreen. You can verify this theory by turning on `Scrolling View` on iBooks. When `Scrolling View` is on, all images, no matter how big, can be rendered onscreen.

PS: *Wow. Stackoverflow does not allow comments (to seek clarification) on answers (need 50 reputation points). But it allows me to post an answer?*